# Photoswipe: Redirecting back a page upon closing gallery

Tags: history.js, photoswipe

I am implementing Photoswipe into a website, and I cannot get the PIDs to work, which is causing the page to redirect back a page when I close the gallery. E.g., if I am at google.com, then I open my index.html file, I click on a thumbnail, the photoswipe gallery opens, then I close the gallery and it redirects back to google.com. I feel this might be because there are no PIDs, and that the URL isn't changing when I am inside the gallery. I am do not know javascript, and that is really hurting me right now. I've tried everything I can think of. I've even copied all the code (html, css, and js) from the photoswipe.com index page where the PIDs are working, but with no luck. I am not sure where the history.js file is to be in my file structure. I'm really just lost. I've set the History option to true. Where am I going wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" debug="true">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">    
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>PhotoSwipe: Responsive JavaScript Image Gallery</title>

    <meta name="description" content="Touch-friendly JavaScript image gallery for mobile and desktop, without dependencies. Responsive layout. Swipe and zoom gestures.">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0"> 

    <meta name="author" content="Dmitry Semenov">
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://photoswipe.com">

    <meta property="og:url" content="http://photoswipe.com">
    <meta property="og:title" content="PhotoSwipe: Responsive JavaScript Image Gallery">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Touch-friendly JavaScript image gallery for mobile and desktop, without dependencies. Responsive layout. Swipe and zoom gestures.">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://photoswipe.com/test/horizontal-swipe.jpg">

    <link href="https://plus.google.com/102586375605352607718" rel="publisher" />


    <link rel="icon apple-touch-icon" href="test/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" sizes="144x144" type="image/png">
    <link href="site-assets/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../dist/photoswipe.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../dist/default-skin/default-skin.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="src/js/history.js"></script>
      <script src="../dist/photoswipe.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../dist/photoswipe-ui-default.min.js"></script>

     <script src="//use.typekit.net/snf1yod.js"></script>
    <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>




      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
       <script>
          document.createElement('figure');
       </script>
      <![endif]-->
  </head>
<body>

    <div class="section section--head">

        <div class="row row--heading">
            <h1>PhotoSwipe<a href="https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/releases"> v4.1.0</a></h1>
            <p>JavaScript gallery, no dependencies.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div id="demo-test-gallery" class="demo-gallery">

            <a href="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_c265dfa55f_h.jpg" data-size="1600x1600" data-med="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_b016d7d289_b.jpg" data-med-size="1024x1024" data-author="Folkert Gorter" class="demo-gallery__img--main">
              <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_b016d7d289_m.jpg" alt="" />
              <figure>This is dummy caption.</figure>
            </a>

            <a href="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5591/15008867125_b61960af01_h.jpg" data-size="1600x1068" data-med="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5591/15008867125_68a8ed88cc_b.jpg" data-med-size="1024x683" data-author="Samuel Rohl">
              <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5591/15008867125_68a8ed88cc_m.jpg" alt="" />
              <figure>This is dummy caption. It has been placed here solely to demonstrate the look and feel of finished, typeset text.</figure>
            </a>


            <a href="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3902/14985871946_24f47d4b53_h.jpg" data-size="1600x1067" data-med="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3902/14985871946_86abb8c56f_b.jpg" data-med-size="1024x683" data-author="Ales Krivec">
              <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3902/14985871946_86abb8c56f_m.jpg" alt="" />
              <figure>This is dummy caption. It is not meant to be read.</figure>
            </a>


            <a href="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5584/14985868676_b51baa4071_h.jpg" data-size="1600x1067" data-med="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5584/14985868676_4b802b932a_b.jpg" data-med-size="1024x683" data-author="Michael Hull">
              <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5584/14985868676_4b802b932a_m.jpg" alt="" />
              <figure>Dummy caption. It's Greek to you. Unless, of course, you're Greek, in which case, it really makes no sense.</figure>
            </a>

            <a href="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3920/15008465772_d50c8f0531_h.jpg" data-size="1600x1067" data-med="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3920/15008465772_383e697089_b.jpg" data-med-size="1024x683" data-author="Thomas Lefebvre">
              <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3920/15008465772_383e697089_m.jpg" alt="" />
              <figure>It's a dummy caption. He who searches for meaning here will be sorely disappointed.</figure>
            </a>

          </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="gallery" class="pswp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="pswp__bg"></div>

        <div class="pswp__scroll-wrap">

          <div class="pswp__container">
            <div class="pswp__item"></div>
            <div class="pswp__item"></div>
            <div class="pswp__item"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="pswp__ui pswp__ui--hidden">

            <div class="pswp__top-bar">

                <div class="pswp__counter"></div>

                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--close" title="Close (Esc)"></button>

                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--share" title="Share"></button>

                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--fs" title="Toggle fullscreen"></button>

                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--zoom" title="Zoom in/out"></button>

                <div class="pswp__preloader">
                    <div class="pswp__preloader__icn">
                      <div class="pswp__preloader__cut">
                        <div class="pswp__preloader__donut"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- <div class="pswp__loading-indicator"><div class="pswp__loading-indicator__line"></div></div> -->

            <div class="pswp__share-modal pswp__share-modal--hidden pswp__single-tap">
                <div class="pswp__share-tooltip">
                    <!-- <a href="#" class="pswp__share--facebook"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="pswp__share--twitter"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="pswp__share--pinterest"></a>
                    <a href="#" download class="pswp__share--download"></a> -->
                </div>
            </div>

            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--left" title="Previous (arrow left)"></button>
            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--right" title="Next (arrow right)"></button>
            <div class="pswp__caption">
              <div class="pswp__caption__center">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>


    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {

        var initPhotoSwipeFromDOM = function(gallerySelector) {

            var parseThumbnailElements = function(el) {
                var thumbElements = el.childNodes,
                    numNodes = thumbElements.length,
                    items = [],
                    el,
                    childElements,
                    thumbnailEl,
                    size,
                    item;

                for(var i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
                    el = thumbElements[i];

                    // include only element nodes 
                    if(el.nodeType !== 1) {
                      continue;
                    }

                    childElements = el.children;

                    size = el.getAttribute('data-size').split('x');

                    // create slide object
                    item = {
                        src: el.getAttribute('href'),
                        w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
                        h: parseInt(size[1], 10),
                        author: el.getAttribute('data-author')
                    };

                    item.el = el; // save link to element for getThumbBoundsFn

                    if(childElements.length > 0) {
                      item.msrc = childElements[0].getAttribute('src'); // thumbnail url
                      if(childElements.length > 1) {
                          item.title = childElements[1].innerHTML; // caption (contents of figure)
                      }
                    }


                    var mediumSrc = el.getAttribute('data-med');
                    if(mediumSrc) {
                        size = el.getAttribute('data-med-size').split('x');
                        // "medium-sized" image
                        item.m = {
                            src: mediumSrc,
                            w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
                            h: parseInt(size[1], 10)
                        };
                    }
                    // original image
                    item.o = {
                        src: item.src,
                        w: item.w,
                        h: item.h
                    };

                    items.push(item);
                }

                return items;
            };

            // find nearest parent element
            var closest = function closest(el, fn) {
                return el && ( fn(el) ? el : closest(el.parentNode, fn) );
            };

            var onThumbnailsClick = function(e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;

                var eTarget = e.target || e.srcElement;

                var clickedListItem = closest(eTarget, function(el) {
                    return el.tagName === 'A';
                });

                if(!clickedListItem) {
                    return;
                }

                var clickedGallery = clickedListItem.parentNode;

                var childNodes = clickedListItem.parentNode.childNodes,
                    numChildNodes = childNodes.length,
                    nodeIndex = 0,
                    index;

                for (var i = 0; i < numChildNodes; i++) {
                    if(childNodes[i].nodeType !== 1) { 
                        continue; 
                    }

                    if(childNodes[i] === clickedListItem) {
                        index = nodeIndex;
                        break;
                    }
                    nodeIndex++;
                }

                if(index >= 0) {
                    openPhotoSwipe( index, clickedGallery );
                }
                return false;
            };

            var photoswipeParseHash = function() {
                var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1),
                params = {};

                if(hash.length < 5) { // pid=1
                    return params;
                }

                var vars = hash.split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
                    if(!vars[i]) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    var pair = vars[i].split('=');  
                    if(pair.length < 2) {
                        continue;
                    }           
                    params[pair[0]] = pair[1];
                }

                if(params.gid) {
                    params.gid = parseInt(params.gid, 10);
                }

                return params;
            };

            var openPhotoSwipe = function(index, galleryElement, disableAnimation, fromURL) {
                var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0],
                    gallery,
                    options,
                    items;

                items = parseThumbnailElements(galleryElement);

                // define options (if needed)
                options = {

                    galleryUID: galleryElement.getAttribute('data-pswp-uid'),

                    getThumbBoundsFn: function(index) {
                        // See Options->getThumbBoundsFn section of docs for more info
                        var thumbnail = items[index].el.children[0],
                            pageYScroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                            rect = thumbnail.getBoundingClientRect(); 

                        return {x:rect.left, y:rect.top + pageYScroll, w:rect.width};
                    },

                    addCaptionHTMLFn: function(item, captionEl, isFake) {
                        if(!item.title) {
                            captionEl.children[0].innerText = '';
                            return false;
                        }
                        captionEl.children[0].innerHTML = item.title +  '<br/><small>Photo: ' + item.author + '</small>';
                        return true;
                    }

                };


                if(fromURL) {
                    if(options.galleryPIDs) {
                        // parse real index when custom PIDs are used 
                        // http://photoswipe.com/documentation/faq.html#custom-pid-in-url
                        for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                            if(items[j].pid == index) {
                                options.index = j;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        options.index = parseInt(index, 10) - 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    options.index = parseInt(index, 10);
                }

                // exit if index not found
                if( isNaN(options.index) ) {
                    return;
                }



                var radios = document.getElementsByName('gallery-style');
                for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
                    if (radios[i].checked) {
                        if(radios[i].id == 'radio-all-controls') {

                        } else if(radios[i].id == 'radio-minimal-black') {
                            options.mainClass = 'pswp--minimal--dark';
                            options.barsSize = {top:0,bottom:0};
                            options.captionEl = false;
                            options.fullscreenEl = false;
                            options.shareEl = false;
                            options.bgOpacity = 0.85;
                            options.tapToClose = true;
                            options.tapToToggleControls = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(disableAnimation) {
                    options.showAnimationDuration = 0;
                }

                // Pass data to PhotoSwipe and initialize it
                gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);

                // see: http://photoswipe.com/documentation/responsive-images.html
                var realViewportWidth,
                    useLargeImages = false,
                    firstResize = true,
                    imageSrcWillChange;

                gallery.listen('beforeResize', function() {

                    var dpiRatio = window.devicePixelRatio ? window.devicePixelRatio : 1;
                    dpiRatio = Math.min(dpiRatio, 2.5);
                    realViewportWidth = gallery.viewportSize.x * dpiRatio;


                    if(realViewportWidth >= 1200 || (!gallery.likelyTouchDevice && realViewportWidth > 800) || screen.width > 1200 ) {
                        if(!useLargeImages) {
                            useLargeImages = true;
                            imageSrcWillChange = true;
                        }

                    } else {
                        if(useLargeImages) {
                            useLargeImages = false;
                            imageSrcWillChange = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if(imageSrcWillChange && !firstResize) {
                        gallery.invalidateCurrItems();
                    }

                    if(firstResize) {
                        firstResize = false;
                    }

                    imageSrcWillChange = false;

                });

                gallery.listen('gettingData', function(index, item) {
                    if( useLargeImages ) {
                        item.src = item.o.src;
                        item.w = item.o.w;
                        item.h = item.o.h;
                    } else {
                        item.src = item.m.src;
                        item.w = item.m.w;
                        item.h = item.m.h;
                    }
                });

                gallery.init();
            };

            // select all gallery elements
            var galleryElements = document.querySelectorAll( gallerySelector );
            for(var i = 0, l = galleryElements.length; i < l; i++) {
                galleryElements[i].setAttribute('data-pswp-uid', i+1);
                galleryElements[i].onclick = onThumbnailsClick;
            }

            // Parse URL and open gallery if it contains #&pid=3&gid=1
            var hashData = photoswipeParseHash();
            if(hashData.pid && hashData.gid) {
                openPhotoSwipe( hashData.pid,  galleryElements[ hashData.gid - 1 ], true, true );
            }
        };

        initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('.demo-gallery');

    })();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running index.html on a local server?

I was having this same issue with PIDs when I directly pulled my HTML file into the browser, but it works like a charm if I'm using BrowserSync.

Comment: I put it on an FTP server, and it worked in Safari but not in Chrome. The PIDs just wouldn't show up. Then, the next day, they did. Go figure. I still don't know what was going on. But it works now, thank goodness!